# Is it possible to enable exit on error behavior in an interactive Tcl shell?

Tags: automation, tcl, expect, tclsh

I need to automate a huge interactive Tcl program using Tcl expect.

As I realized, this territory is really dangerous, as I need to extend the already existing mass of code, but I can't rely on errors actually causing the program to fail with a positive exit code as I could in a regular script.
This means I have to think about every possible thing that could go wrong and "expect" it.

What I currently do is use a "die" procedure instead of raising an error in my own code, that automatically exits. But this kind of error condition can not be `catch`ed, and makes it hard to detect errors especially in code not written by me, since ultimately, most library routines will be `error`-based.

Since I have access to the program's Tcl shell, is it possible to enable fail-on-error?

EDIT:

I am using Tcl 8.3, which is a severe limitation in terms of available tools.

Examples of errors I'd like to automatically exit on:

```
% puts $a(2)
can't read "a(2)": no such element in array
while evaluating {puts $a(2)}
%

% blublabla
invalid command name "blublabla"
while evaluating blublabla
%
```

As well as any other error that makes a normal script terminate.
These can bubble up from 10 levels deep within procedure calls.

I also tried redefining the global `error` command, but not all errors that can occur in Tcl use it. For instance, the above "command not found" error did not go through my custom `error` procedure.

Comment: Can you update your post to include an example Tcl script you want to automate. Can you make it show what kind of `error` occurrences you want to make exit?

Comment: 8.3 is well over a decade out of even extended support...

Answer (score 0):

> Since I have access to the program's Tcl shell, is it possible to
>   enable fail-on-error?

Let me try to summarize in my words: You want to exit from an interactive Tcl shell upon error, rather than having the prompt offered again?

### Update

> I am using Tcl 8.3, which is a severe limitation in terms of available
>   tools [...] only source patches to the C code.

As you seem to be deep down in that rabbit hole, why not add another source patch?

```
--- tclMain.c   2002-03-26 03:26:58.000000000 +0100
+++ tclMain.c.mrcalvin  2019-10-23 22:49:14.000000000 +0200
@@ -328,6 +328,7 @@
        Tcl_WriteObj(errChannel, Tcl_GetObjResult(interp));
        Tcl_WriteChars(errChannel, "\n", 1);
        }
+       Tcl_Exit(1);
    } else if (tsdPtr->tty) {
        resultPtr = Tcl_GetObjResult(interp);
        Tcl_GetStringFromObj(resultPtr, &length);
```

This is untested, the Tcl 8.3.5 sources don't compile for me. But this section of Tcl's internal are comparable to current sources, tested using my Tcl 8.6 source installation.

### For the records

With a stock shell (`tclsh`), this is a little fiddly, I am afraid. The following might work for you (though, I can imagine cases where this might fail you). The idea is

- to intercept writes to `stderr` (this is to where an interactive shell redirects error messages, before returning to the prompt).
- to discriminate between arbitrary writes to `stderr` and error cases, one can use the global variable `::errorInfo` as a sentinel.

### Step 1: Define a channel interceptor

```
oo::class create Bouncer {
    method initialize {handle mode} {
        if {$mode ne "write"} {error "can't handle reading"}
        return {finalize initialize write}
    }
    method finalize {handle} {
        # NOOP
    }

    method write {handle bytes} {
        if {[info exists ::errorInfo]} {
        # This is an actual error;
        # 1) Print the message (as usual), but to stdout
        fconfigure stdout -translation binary
        puts stdout $bytes
        # 2) Call on [exit] to quit the Tcl process
        exit 1
    } else {
        # Non-error write to stderr, proceed as usual
            return $bytes
    }
    }
}
```

### Step 2: Register the interceptor for `stderr` in interactive shells

```
if {[info exists ::tcl_interactive]} {
    chan push stderr [Bouncer new]
}
```

Once registered, this will make your interactive shell behave like so:

```
% puts stderr "Goes, as usual!"
Goes, as usual!
% error "Bye, bye"
Bye, bye
```

### Some remarks

- You need to be careful about the `Bouncer`'s `write` method, the error message has already been massaged for the character encoding (therefore, the `fconfigure` call).
- You might want to put this into a Tcl package or Tcl module, to load the bouncer using `package req`.
- I could imagine that your program writes to `stderr` and the `errorInfo` variable happens to be set (as a left-over), this will trigger an unintended exit.

Comment: You might also render the `write` method more robust, by a general `try {...} finally {exit 1}` in the error-branch?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, your 3rd remark is exactly the case, already as my program to be automated starts up. I also don't have access to "oo", but I guess I could invent an alternative based off your stderr channel handling idea if it solved my problem.

Comment: What is the exact Tcl version you are running?

Comment: 8.3 . So I could not even use "try", as you suggested. It also has some custom in-house binary patches by people who are long gone from the company, which even causes extra stuff to be printed when some errors occur. Not when others though...

Comment: With 8.3, none of the above is in reach, I am afraid. Any chance of upgrading?

Comment: none at all. Yeah, I just went to the docs page and saw that not even "chan" is available in 8.3, so even if I could hack my way around using "oo", it would not work.

Comment: One correction: we don't actually have binary patches, only source patches to the C code.

Comment: In 8.3 (really?!) It might be easier to define your own REPL rather than using the default in Tclsh. It isn't very much code (with `info complete` to help); code should be on the Tcler's Wiki. The fancy tools of later versions aren't available in a codebase that old...